# Switching to TMB mode in AD Studio

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, emacs

I am trying to become familiar with `TMB` in `AD Studio`.  I have been working through the user's guide `AD Studio: Statistical modelling in ADMB and TMB Version 1.0 (2018-01-22)` by Arni Magnusson.  I can follow the initial section of the guide focusing on `ADMB` and the examples run as expected.  However, once the guide switches to `TMB` I encounter a problem.  The guide says to press `F3` to switch to `tmb-mode`.  However, when I press `F3` on my `Windows 10` laptop the only option offered is to adjust the volume of the laptop's speakers.  Apparently if I do switch to `tmb-mode` I might need to press `F2` to switch back to `admb-mode` but pressing the `F2` key only allows me to adjust the speaker volume as well.

Is there an alternative method of accessing `tmb-mode` in `AD Studio`?  Or perhaps is there a way to switch the laptop's `F3` key to activate `tmb-mode` and the `F2` key to activate the `admb-mode`?

I am not sure whether `TMB` is a stand-alone application.  There is a `TMB` `R` package and I have installed that in `R`.

Answer (score 0):

My `Dell XPS 15 9570` laptop comes with an `Fn` key. If I press this `Fn` key + the `F2` key (or the `Fn` key + the `F3` key) then `AD Studio` will switch `modes`.